# What is the reason for creating the symbols ∞ on the client side?

Tags: javascript, server-side, client-side

Take a look at this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60766/what-is-the-result-of-infinity-minus-infinity

What is the reason for transforming the symbols ∞ on the client side?

Because if someone disable javascript, this is what they see:

[image]

So right now I'm pondering what may be the reasons for that decision *(I was thinking there are bound to be some advantage otherwise the decision wouldn't have been done)*.

Comment: Note that the math in question doesn't always transform into unicode characters. You could replace something like $\infty$ with a character easily, but more complicated math would have to be an image (or look really ugly).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few possible reasons:

- The JavaScript library for this already existed, so it required little development time to deploy, as no major changes were required in their code base.
- It saves processing time on the server from not having to generate the images.
- It saves bandwidth, as the LaTeX code is much more compact than the rendered images.
- It avoids frequent round-trips to the server while editing a post, allowing for a smoother user experience. (The LaTeX is rendered live in the preview.)

Comment: why not use MathML instead?

Comment: @oenone While MathML is great in theory, browser support is far from perfect. The number of people having JavaScript disabled is far lower than the number of people having a MathML incompatible browser.